# What's the use of polymer paper-icon-button?

Tags: javascript, polymer

According to the [polymer document](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-icon-button), the paper-icon-button has properties like `active` and `toggle`. But how can one read the button state out using the 'polymer way'?

With the help of @Joel Turcotte Gaucher, I wrote the following code. However, it still does not toggle as I click the button. Is there something I missed?

```
<dom-module id="todo-app">                                                      
    <template>   
    <paper-toolbar>                                                             
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" active="{{isActive}}" toggle="{{isToggle}}"></paper-icon-button>
        <span class="title">TodoSlacker</span>                                  
    </paper-toolbar>      
    <p>                                                                             
    Active: {{isActive}} <br>                                                       
    Toggle: {{isToggle}}                                                            
    </p>  
    </template>                                                                   
    <script>                                                                      
    Polymer({                                                                   
      is: "todo-app",                                                           
      properties: {                                                             
        isActive: Boolean,                                                      
        isToggle: Boolean             
     }
    });                                                                         
    </script>                                                                     
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the property to a value.

```
<p>
  Active: {{isActive}} <br> // The button is toggle!
</p>
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" active="{{isActive}}" toggles raised >Tap Me</paper-icon-button>
```

Comment: In the webpage, it shows `Active: false 
Toggle:`, and they don't change as I click the button. Did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks very much. It is working now. I also tried without `raised`, it seems to work too. What does `raised` do?